# Getting the Error Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError - No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, jruby

I am using the AWS S3 client to upload a pdf file from a web application which runs on Ruby (jruby in particular). I am getting the following Error

**Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError - No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate):**

Do you what's the issue that might be causing this?

`

```
require 'aws-sdk'

client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: "asia-south1",
                             credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(access_key,secret_key),
                             endpoint: endpoint,
                             force_path_style: true
)
resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: client)
bucket = resource.bucket(bucket_name)
unique_key = file_name
object = bucket.object(unique_key)
if File.exists?(path + file_name)
  object.upload_file(path + file_name)
end
```

`

The files are getting uploaded successfully when I am using the same access keys from a different web application that runs on Ruby stack.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're missing the [JRuby OpenSSL gem](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl) which is used to emulate Ruby's native OpenSSL library. Add the following to your Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'jruby-openssl', platforms: :jruby
```

Run `bundle install` and then retry the operation with JRuby.

If that doesn't resolve the issue then double-check that your JVM is compiled with support for a full cipher suite:

```bash
jruby -ropenssl -e 'OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new.ciphers.each { |c| p c}'
```

This should return something like:

```
["TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 128]
["ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 128]
["DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 128]
["DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 128]
["ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 128]
["ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 128]
["AES256-GCM-SHA384", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 384]
["AES128-GCM-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["AES256-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["AES128-SHA256", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 256]
["AES256-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 256, 256]
["AES128-SHA", "TLSv1/SSLv3", 128, 128]
```

If not then you'll need to change the way that you're installing the JVM. If you're using a pre-built version from a package manager like apt or yum then you may need to switch to [building the JVM from source](https://openjdk.org/groups/build/doc/building.html), and likewise if you're building from source you'll likely want to switch to using a [pre-built package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/openjdk-18-jre-headless) with SSL support.